# Stata's xtlogit (fe, re) equivalent in R?

Tags: r, stata, logistic-regression

Stata allows for fixed effects and random effects specification of the logistic regression through the [xtlogit](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtlogit.pdf) fe and [xtlogit](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtlogit.pdf) re commands accordingly. I was wondering what are the equivalent commands for these specifications in R.

The only similar specification I am aware of is the mixed effects logistic regression

```
mymixedlogit <- glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 +  x3 + (1 | x4), data = d, family = binomial)
```

but I am not sure whether this maps to any of the aforementioned commands.

Comment: it's hard to know without more details on the meaning of the equivalent Stata function: can you edit your question to provide a link?

Comment: My experience with reading the Stata documentation was very painful. Compared to its opaque character, reading the R documentation in the help pages was a piece of cake. (And people do complain about R help pages.) I would think a link to a full tutorial would be more helpful than a link to Stata help pages.

Comment: `melogit` and `xtmelogit` (superseded by `meqrlogit` in Stata 13), are the commands for mixed effects regression for binary/binomial responses.

Comment: @BondedDust Why did you find Stata documentation painful? I actually think it's one of its strong features and by that I mean that it's **really** good. Straightforward, clear, concise, with relevant examples. And I'm just talking about `help <command>`. The manuals elaborate with details and offer methods, additional examples and commentaries.

Comment: This is clear? http://www.stata.com/manuals13/degen.pdf

Comment: @BondedDust Your profile says "Learned R on my own and have used it daily for last 4+ years." Give us the equivalent statement for Stata and we will be clear on why you find Stata documentation more difficult. FWIW, I learned Stata on my own and have used it daily for last 23+ years, have used R much, much less and find it harder work, but the plausible explanation starts with myself, not the documentation.

Comment: @BondedDust That's pretty much like saying that a written cooking recipe is opaque because the person doesn't know how to read at all.
The _Stata User's Guide_, on page 4 (four), **strongly** recommends to read Chapter 11 on _Language Syntax_.
There, _Syntax diagrams_ are explained, and this is a key point in understanding important parts of Stata documentation.
Presumably, this is what you refer to as "opaque" in your first comment. Syntax diagrams allow users to check 
command functionality in a relatively short amount of time.

Comment: @BondedDust Even if you decide to skip Syntax description, there's enough information in what's
left of the entry to understand some functionality and write working code. `egen`s entry, quite a special command in my opinion,
has 4.5 pages of Syntax and 15.5 pages of non-Syntax sections. 
It's up to the user to decide if it's in his own interest
to learn how to read the documentation. The introduction/first-part of any book usually contains vital information.

Comment: I don't think R has an `xtlogit, fe` analog, which is a conditional logit rather than a logit with indicators. statsRus provides the `xtlogit, re` solution below, but I expect that the convergence criteria differ, so you may get very different answers. My guess is that Stata's convergence criteria is more strict, but I don't have a lot experience benchmarking the two.

Answer (score 4):

The `glmer` command is used to quickly fit logistic regression models with varying intercepts and varying slopes (or, equivalently, a mixed model with fixed and random effects).

To fit a varying intercept multilevel logistic regression model in R (that is, a random effects logistic regression model), you can run the following using the in-built "mtcars" data set:

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
m <- glmer(mtcars$am ~ 1 + mtcars$wt + (1|mtcars$gear), family="binomial")
summary(m)   

# and you can examine the fixed and random effects
fixef(m); ranef(m)
```

To fit a varying-intercept slope model in Stata, you of course use the xtlogit command (using the similar but not identical in-built "auto" data set in Stata):

```
sysuse auto
xtset gear_ratio
xtlogit foreign weight, re
```

I'll add that I find the entire reference to "fixed" versus "random" effects ambiguous, and I prefer to refer to the structure of the model itself (e.g., are the intercepts varying? which slopes are varying, if any? is the model nested in 2 levels or more? are the levels cross-classified or not?). For a similar view, see Andrew Gelman's [thoughts](http://andrewgelman.com/2005/01/25/why_i_dont_use/) on "fixed" versus "random" effects.

Update: Ben Bolker's excellent comment below points out that in R it's more informative when using `predict` commands to use the `data=mtcars` option instead of, say, the dollar notation:

```
data(mtcars)
m1 <- glmer(mtcars$am ~ 1 + mtcars$wt + (1|mtcars$gear), family="binomial")
m2 <- glmer(am ~ 1 + wt + (1|gear), family="binomial", data=mtcars)
p1 <- predict(m1); p2 <- predict(m2)
names(p1) # not that informative...
names(p2) # very informative!
```

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with the point that "fixed" and "random" are confusing terms. Had I been responsible for naming them I might have chosen "arbitrary" or "convenience" for what is currently termed "random" and used "focus" or maybe even "random" for what are now called "fixed". The current practice using variables denoted as "random" is not choosing them by a randomized process nor are assignments allocated randomly from a representative sample.

Comment: one tiny nitpick: probably better to say `glmer(am ~ 1 + wt + (1|gear), data=mtcars, family="binomial")`; easier to read and work better with downstream accessors such as `predict`

Comment: Useful to mention that the `glmer`-function is part of the `lme4`-package.